# Getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found when using Kafka Consumer to hit API

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, kafka-consumer-api, httpsession

My requirement is to fetch cookie from the API requests and then pass on the same cookie to subsequent requests in order to maintain session using the same JsessionID.

For that I am trying to fetch cookie using HttpHeaders by Autowiring HttpServletRequests.
If I hit an API using Controller I don't get any exception and I am able to fetch all the request attributes but if I run Kafka and API runs through Kafka Consumer, I am getting below exception:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.*

```
  @Autowired
  HttpServletRequest req;
  
  @Autowired
  HttpServletResponse res;
 
 public ResponseBean putData() {

    String jsessionId = null;
    String id = null;

    // Creating Headers for request
    String authValue = req.getHeader("authorization");
    String headerCookie = req.getHeader("Cookie");


    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("authorization", authValue);
    httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, headerCookie);


    HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange
            ("https://url", HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, String.class);
    jsessionId = responseEntity.getHeaders().getFirst("Set-Cookie");


    if (jsessionId !=null && jsessionId.contains("JSESSION")) {
        logger.info("New login session created");
        id = jsessionId.substring(jsessionId.indexOf('=') + 1, jsessionId.indexOf(';'));
       
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("JSESSIONID", id);
        res.addCookie(cookie);
    }
```

}

PS- I am not using SpringSecurity.

Can anyone please help me in fixing the above issue.

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet?

Comment: Hi Gray... I have updated above problem with code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found:

This exception is trying to tell you that there is no current request being processed by the `HttpServletRequest` that has been auto-wired into your class.

Something is calling the `putData()` method but not as through a call to the HTTP controller.  You mention that you are using the "Kafka Consumer" so maybe it is the consumer code which is calling `putData()`?  You can't call it because the method needs to have a web request context to work since it needs the request headers and cookie information.

You should probably separate out the data persistence code so that both the controller `putData()` method and the kafka consumer can both call it.

Comment: Thanks Gray for the pointers.
Yes putData() is directly being called by my consumer and not through controller.
Will it be correct if I call my controller API through consumer in the same project?
And then through controller I will call putData().

Comment: Sorry @DeepikaSwarup.  I don't know enough about your application to answer appropriately.

Comment: Thanks Gray for the pointers... It helped me in getting more insight and fixing it. Since there was no controller involved and Kafka was calling PUT method directly, I was unable to get HTTP context... In order to resolve my issue, I created an inmemory map...

Comment: @DeepikaSwarup - I am also having a similar approach of calling a Remote Service using
Spring HTTPInvoker from Kafka Consumer and getting the same above error. i am stuck
with no ways to get further, can you explain a bit more on how and what you did with
inmemory map ? Related question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72999102/1764587

Comment: Hi @Dinesh... I had used Inmemory map to store authorization related data. Can you please help me explain your issue more.